# Laptop turns off after 20 minutes of use

Tags: cpu, process, hardware-failure, fan, sony-vaio

My laptop a sony vaio VGN-NW11S http://www.trustedreviews.com/Sony-VAIO-VGN-NW11S-S---15-5in-Laptop_Laptop_review.

Everytime i turn it on, in safe mode or not, if i try to open an application i.e. run a process such as google chrome or event viewer, defrag, virus scan, it completely turns off without warning, nor giving a trace of events the next time I switch it on.

Apart from that, I had worries it might be my battery or power supply but I dont think it is that, I took the laptop apart cleaning fans etc. and have ordered some cpu paste as I checked to see the condition of the processor. I will post to see if re-applying the paste works.

One more thing, when the heavy processes kick in, the fan starts to make a lot of noise, maybe trying to cool down the CPU?

Any ideas on what else it could be and what I could do to test what is wrong?

Comment: Can you check temperature readings in the BIOS? If so, what are they showing?

Comment: will post after 17.00h

Comment: Sounds like temp related, failing that memory/hdd fault

Comment: It sounds like the CPU is overheating.

Answer (score 1):

Noisy fan is a problem with some Sony models, and they have done a recall of sorts to fix this.  See http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/news-item.pl?news_id=299&mdl=VGNCS290J

Also, my Sony occasionally gets in a state where the charger circuitry detects an overcharge condition and kills the system.  You hear a "blink!" and the system goes black.  The solution to this is to run the box on battery for at least 30 minutes, plus, if your system supports it, go into VAIO Control Center/Power Management/Battery Charge Functions and enable the "Battery Care Function" for 80% charge.

You can also get a situation where the CPU (on my dual core model) runs at 50% (causing elevated temps), but resets to normal (5-10%) when you reboot, sleep, or hibernate the box.  This is due to "wild" interrupts, and the solution in my case is to never turn off the WiFi radio, even when running cable-connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot dan, that matches the problems i am having, i'll have a look soon to see if I can change a few settings, my battery is on the brink, so buying a new one might be crucial

Answer (score 0):

In my long experience of using a computer, a computer can go to sudden death due to excess heat received from the processor. Especially for laptops that are not recommended to be used 24 hours. Excessive heat on the IC processor will tell the data signal to the center of the CPU to immediately shut down (OFF) to prevent fatal damage to the device. This includes the computer program for security measures for the device itself. Usually attached to the bottom and serve directly as a mat or pad the bottom of your laptop.

Try to check and look at your laptop, does it feel hot if it has been in turn all this time. To move as the solution you try to add extra cooling a fan / small fan that is now being sold in stores and selling computer center in your area.

Do not forget to open the BIOS settings on your laptop, if you know about the BIOS settings on the column there are manual settings for the temperature of the cooling fan or fans that we want. But my advice is best to leave it in the default position. It is important for the security of your computer system or laptop.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the problem is heat in this case.